# Joining tables and expecting null results from second table

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables that I'm trying to combine. The left table I'm expecting to show all EmbroideryID's while the right table is supposed to return null's for those EmbroideryID's. However, I'm only getting the EmbroideryID's that exist in both tables, which is not what I want. I want all the results from my left table regardless if there is results for my right table.

Left Table:

`mysql> SELECT * FROM Embroidery WHERE Customer = 'AAAAAAAA';
+--------------+----------+--------------------------+
| EmbroideryID | Customer | Description              |
+--------------+----------+--------------------------+
|            1 | AAAAAAAA | Embroidery1              |
|            2 | AAAAAAAA | Embroidery2              |
|            3 | AAAAAAAA | Embroidery3              |
|            4 | AAAAAAAA | Embroidery4              |
|            5 | AAAAAAAA | Embroidery5              |
+--------------+----------+--------------------------+`

Right Table:

`SELECT * FROM EmbroideryForMen;
+----------+--------------+-----------+
| Customer | EmbroideryID | ManNumber |
+----------+--------------+-----------+
| AAAAAAAA |            1 |         4 |
| AAAAAAAA |            1 |         8 |
| AAAAAAAA |            1 |        12 |
+----------+--------------+-----------+`

What I'm expecting is this:

`+--------------+----------+--------------------------+-----------+
| EmbroideryID | Customer | Description              | ManNumber |
+--------------+----------+--------------------------+-----------+
|            1 | AAAAAAAA | Embroidery1              |         4 |
|            1 | AAAAAAAA | Embroidery2              |         8 |
|            1 | AAAAAAAA | Embroidery3              |        12 |
|            2 | AAAAAAAA | Embroidery4              |      NULL |
|            3 | AAAAAAAA | Embroidery5              |      NULL |
|            4 | AAAAAAAA | Embroidery5              |      NULL |
|            5 | AAAAAAAA | Embroidery5              |      NULL |
+--------------+----------+--------------------------+-----------+`

Here is also a SQLFiddle that you can look at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/579bac/3

The reason I'm wanting to see the table like this is because not all the time will a user will select a person to receive an Embroidery, so the row / record will never be created. I want to avoid writing in null records to the EmbroideryForMen, but If need be, I'll do it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause should limit on the columns of the left table (`e`), rather then the right left joined table (`m`), and of course, remove the limit on embroideryid on it: [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/579bac/10). Important to remember is: the columns of the `LEFT JOIN`ed table will all be NULL, so don't add columns in the `WHERE` clause checking them, unless you explicitly _want_ to check for non-existence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve it:

replace the `m.customer = "AAAAAAAA"` by `e.customer = "AAAAAAAA"` (because m.customer could be null and null != "AAAAAAAA") and
remove the `AND e.EmbroideryID = 1` (to display all rows)

```
SELECT * 
FROM Embroidery e 
LEFT JOIN EmbroideryForMen m 
ON e.EmbroideryID = m.EmbroideryID
  AND e.Customer = m.Customer
WHERE e.Customer = "AAAAAAAA";
```

Comment: Thank you! I made the mistake of putting in the `EmbroideryID = '1'` in the fiddle. I can't believe I made that little mistake for it!

Answer (score 1):

When doing a `left join`, conditions on the *second* table should go in the `on` clause.  Otherwise, the values are `NULL` and will fail most comparisons in the `where` clause.  Conditions on the first table should go in the `where` clause, otherwise they have no effect.

So, the query that you want is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Embroidery e LEFT JOIN
     EmbroideryForMen m 
     ON e.EmbroideryID = m.EmbroideryID AND
        e.Customer = m.Customer AND
        m.Customer = "AAAAAAAA" AND
        m.EmbroideryID = 1;
```

Comment: You're right just like the answer, however, you'll need to remove the `EmbroideryID = '1'` in the `Where` clause

Comment: @Twister1002 . . . I didn't make up that condition.  It is in the SQL Fiddle.